# editing htaccess [NC,P] rule to accept a number parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess rule as such:

```
RewriteRule ^apply/aff/check/?$ /index.php?task=dupe&format=raw [NC,P]
```

However I want to be able to pass a number that will change into the destination page like this:

`apply/aff/check/X`
as in 
`apply/aff/check/21`

Should be redirected to

```
/index.php?task=dupe&format=raw&number=X
```

as in

```
/index.php?task=dupe&format=raw&number=21
```

However I also need the original to work also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
RewriteRule ^apply/aff/check/?$ /index.php?task=dupe&format=raw [NC,P]

RewriteRule ^apply/aff/check/([0-9]+)?$ /index.php?task=dupe&format=raw&number=$1 [NC,P]
```